# ngfor table group by date

Tags: javascript, html, angular

How do I use *ngFor to create a HTML table group by date in columns.
This is a example of json List:

[{
"id": "700",
"FamilyDesc": "MERCEDES",
"model": "Mercedes-BenzClasse A",
"cost": "60000" "date": "21/09/2022"
}, {
"id": "700",
"FamilyDesc": "MERCEDES",
"model": "Mercedes-BenzClasse A",
"cost": "30000" "date": "01/01/2021"
}, {
"id": "700",
"FamilyDesc": "MERCEDES",
"model": "Mercedes-BenzClasse B",
"cost": "50000" "date": "01/01/2022"
}, {
"id": "700",
"FamilyDesc": "MERCEDES",
"model": "Mercedes-BenzClasse B",
"cost": "40000" "date": "01/01/2021"
}, {
"id": "700",
"FamilyDesc": "BMW",
"model": "X4",
"cost": "80000" "date": "01/01/2022"
}, {
"id": "700",
"FamilyDesc": "BMW",
"model": "X4",
"cost": "70000" "date": "01/01/2021"
}
]

what is the best way to have this result:
[example view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ilXz.png)

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using a libary like angular material. Here some examples: https://material.angular.io/components/table.

If you dont want to use a libary you can write a script:
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_sort_table.asp

*ngFor is just used to loop the data in.